# Site branding block wont appear on contact or user login form

Tags: theming

I have a theme and I am able to configure the site branding block to show up on my content type pages and a full-width template I have.  This is because I have {{page.branding}} in the template.

However it wont appear on the contact page or the user login page?  Is it because they are not "pages" or "content types"?  What am I missing?

Comment: Change to a different core theme and if the branding appears we can conclude that  your custom theme is causing this behaviour, but it will be hard to pinpoint why without seeing some code.  One thing you might want to do is enable debugging https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates and see if you can pinpoint the template that is used for `contact` and `user login` and revise your question with something more specific.

Comment: my parent theme is the bootstrap theme and when I look at the templates folder of the sub theme it does not contain the user form template

Comment: If you enable debugging from link above you will be able to tell which twig templates are used and investigate and revise your question with specific code from them.  Otherwise your question is very broad.

Comment: I do know which one it is using.  It is using page.html.twig and it has the {{page.branding}}

Comment: I will look deeper

Comment: You might also want to look in your `MODULENAME.theme` for any preprocessing that might be affecting the branding block.

Comment: You are correct, I did switch back to the bootstrap theme as my default and the site branding block did show up on the contact page.  So now I must figure out why my sub theme is stopping this from happening

Comment: I might have found the reason but need help with a solution, I will repost a new question

Comment: this is my new post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277926/site-branding-block-not-appearing-in-regular-page-html-twig-template