# Site Branding Block not appearing in regular page--html--twig template

Tags: theming

I have a sub theme with the parent theme being the bootstrap theme.  I am able to configure the site branding block to show up on my content type pages and that's because my sub theme has a hook which suggests this full--width--page template.  This full--width--page template has the {{page.branding}} region in it and it works fine.

However it wont appear on the contact page or the user login page? I suspect the boostrap theme or parent drupal engine uses the regular page.html.twig template for contact page and user login page and other pages.  the {{page.branding}} does not seem to work in the page.thml.twig template.

I am looking for possible solutions.  Maybe I ened a hook to tell the theme to use the full--width--page.twig template but I don't know how to write that hook, or maybe I ened to find out what is wrong witht he page--html.twig template.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably override the suggestions using `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter` in your `THEMENAME.theme` file

```
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  //the routes to use the specified template
  $use_template = [
    "user.register", // user/register
    "user.login", // user/login
    "user.pass", // user/password
    "entity.contact_form.canonical", // core contact form (website feedback)
    "entity.webform.canonical", // all webforms will have this route
  ];

  // what route are we on ?   
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

  if (in_array($route_name, $use_template) ){
    $suggestions[] = 'full__width__page';
  }
}
```

You should clear the cache and your specific template should take control.

If you have [twig debugging enabled](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) and your browser has [show html comments enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928172/how-to-hide-html-comments-in-chrome-dev-tools) you should see something similar to this the *page source*

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   X full--width--page.html.twig
   * page--user--register.html.twig
   * page--user.html.twig
   * page.html.twig
-->
```

With x indicating the twig template responsible for the particular output.  In this case `full--width--page.html.twig` is the twig template used.